# Link testing

Tags: testing, soa

What is link testing in SOA testing.
As some of the information i found spoke about link testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link Testing would be the initial testing that starts at the design stage where we create the testcases. The Goal is to test each and every link that forms part of the desgin once the initial code is developed

Comment: I don't like this answer.  It's very vague and not helpful.

Comment: Its a good answer. I think it defines everything in just two sentences.

Answer (score 2):

Link test is to test a group of unit to ensure that the unit operate correctly in combination. It is normally performed after the individual unit have been tested in isolation and prior to the integration testing that is performed for the complete system.

Answer (score 1):

I've not encountered the term before - nor it appears has Google in the context of SOA :-)

However, I would guess that it's the SOA equivalent of Integration Testing. A distiction being that when integrating with other people's services you do not necessarily work so closely with the providers as might be usual for integration tetsting. You may in fact never meet, or even talk to, the service provider - just link to their services. This clearly presents some interesting problem determination challenges.

Answer (score 1):

Link Testing is also called as Component Integration Testing where we are actually testing whether modules are properly liked or not .

Answer (score 1):

Link testing is the way of checking each link of the application to identify
whether every given location is working perfectly and bring up the pages which it
suppose to.